# Centroid for a rectangular section inclined at an angle theta

Tags: geometry

How to find Centroid for a rectangular section inclined at an angle theta? Is there any general formula available?

Comment: What do you mean by a rectangular section?  A section of what?

Comment: A rectangle only.

Comment: As you probably know, it's in the middle, where the diagonals meet. What else needs to be done?

Comment: Yes.I agree with ur point.If it is inclined then how will you calculate along with that inclination angle?

Comment: Take the midpoint of two opposite vertices.

Comment: The centroid is independent of rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the centroid of a body doesn't change with rotation . If you are working in a coordinate system, then only the coordinates of the centroid change (not with respect to the body but with respect to axes). Thus,in a rectangle centroid $(x,y)$ is intersection of two diagonals and if the rectangle is rotated by $\theta$ then  new coordinates$(x',y')$ are given by system of equations $$x'=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$$ and $$y'=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$$

Comment: Thank you Avatar.It's useful.